# How to settle hibernate query java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null?

Tags: hibernate, exception, web, hql

I still can not solve this problem, I see a lot of answers are said to have a wrong grammar, but I feel no problem. My `hibernate` version is `4.3.8.Final`

Here is my program

```
          String hql = "from　CardVoucher　c where c.businessId=:businessId";
                Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                params.put("businessId", businessId);
                vouchers = voucherDao.find(hql, params, page, rows);

public List<T> find(String hql, Map<String, Object> params, int page, int rows) {
        Query q = this.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {
            for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                q.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
            }
        }
        return q.setFirstResult((page - 1) * rows).setMaxResults(rows).list();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your hql is not valid : `from　CardVoucher　c where c.businessId=:businessId` should be `select c from　CardVoucher　c where c.businessId=:businessId`